# Why android.R.id.list 's parent is FrameLayout not LInearLayout in Android N

Tags: android, android-layout, preferencescreen

I get the parent layout of `preferenceScreen` on lower than Android N is the following code :

```
    final Dialog dialog = preferenceScreen.getDialog();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        Log.d("TAG",dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getClass()+"");
        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent();
    } else {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    }
```

Here is the layout of **PreferenceScreen** in  Android source code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_removeBorders="true">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        style="?attr/preferenceFragmentListStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="0dip"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/preference_fragment_padding_bottom"
        android:scrollbarStyle="@integer/preference_fragment_scrollbarStyle"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" />

......other widget......

</LinearLayout>
```

It works well on lower than Android N,But when I run my app in Android N, show error that the parent of **ListView** that id is **android.R.id.list** is **FrameLayout** not **LinearLayout**.
The Android source code explained that it is **LinearLayout** not **FrameLayout**,but why error?

Comment: let me check on this and get back to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make sense to use a `FrameLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` with one child view. This change is most likely permanent. From the deleted answer and comments, I see you are using this [library](https://github.com/davcpas1234/MaterialSettings) and this question is related to this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/davcpas1234/MaterialSettings/issues/6).

My advice would be to discontinue using that library. You should be using a `PreferenceFragment` instead of the deprecated `PreferenceActivity`. If you want to have preferences with material design on pre-L you should use the official [v7 preference support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-preference). However, last I checked this had some pitfalls.

Comment: yeah,the iuuse in Github is opend by me . On pre-M it works well but on N this code is right `LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent();`  But the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is 23 although my phone is Android N